# How to insert new rows in some position in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have page with table.
In `tbody` I show data via `angularjs`. In `thead` I have same row as in `tbody`, but its empty, and when I filled input field and `click` somewhere (focus lost), one row adds to my table (`thead`). And I need to make some flag on filled row, as like - `rowAdded = true`, because without that I clicking on input of one row and rows adds. And one more problem is that rows adds to the end of `table`.
it's all works on this script:

```
var tbody = $('.table-timesheet thead');
tbody.on('blur', ':text', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        notEmpty = $(':text', tr).filter(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).val()) != '';
        }).length;
    if (notEmpty) {
        $('.note-input').css('width', '88%').css('float', 'left');
        $('.timesheet-delete-button').css('display', 'block');
        //tr.clone(true).appendTo(tbody).find(':text').val('');
        insRow();
    }
});

function deleteRow(row) {
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('table-body').deleteRow(i);
}


function insRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById('table-body');
    var newRow = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = table.rows.length;
    newRow.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = newRow.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = newRow.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    table.appendChild(newRow);
}
```

There is my example in plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/rcnwv0Ru8Hmy7Jrf9b1C?p=preview

Comment: It is a little hard to read your question clearly and I think it is really multiple questions in one. Are you trying to add the new row to table head (thead)? If so why do you not want to use tbody? Typically thead is for information regarding what the columns will have. All the overall functionality of adding  a row seems to be broken because everytime I add info in one of the columns its making a new row.

Comment: Demo has no angular code in it. Really seems like you are doing far too much DOM manipulation and also relying on document.ready . Approach is all wrong for working within angular app. You should be updating data model to generate view, not doing your own row insertions. Please update demo so angular at least gets bootstrapped with your controller if you want more help

Comment: @HUSTLIN you should add a tag of angular.js also with it

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for

```js
function insRow(ind){
  var table = document.getElementById('table-body');
  var newRow = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
  var len = table.rows.length;
  newRow.cells[0].innerHTML = ind!==undefined ? ind : len;
  if(ind!==undefined)
       $(table).find('tr:eq('+ind+')').before(newRow);
  else table.appendChild(newRow);
}

insRow(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-body">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```